# Is there a well-known algorithm for allocating planks to trucks?

Tags: algorithm

I have to implement the algorithm described below, and I have two questions:

- Is this problem NP-Complete?
- Is it similar to a well-known
  algorithmic problem?

**The problem**

I have planks of wood of three lengths: 10m, 8m and 5m.

I need to transport these from one place to another.

I have three types trucks I can use for this, Truck A, Truck B and Truck C.

Each truck can carry at most 10 planks, but Truck A can carry all types of planks, and Truck B can only carry planks of 8m and 5m, and Truck C can only carry planks of 5m.

Each Truck has its own price list for transporting planks:

```
Truck A
1 plank $50 
2-5 planks $100
6-10 planks $150

Truck B
1 plank $30
2-5 planks $90
6-10 planks $140

Truck C
1 plank $20
2-5 planks $80
6-10 planks $110
```

The goal of the algorithm: find the cheapest way to transport a certain collection of planks.

Example:
I have 5 planks of 10m, and 1 plank of 8m.

There are two possible distributions:

1. 6 on truck A: $150
2. 5 on Truck A and 1 on Truck B: $100 + $30.

So option 2 is the best. As I start solving this for more planks, the number of possible combinations will grow.

The specific pricelist can change, but it will always remain true that it never saves money to divide planks of the same size over more trucks then needed.

So: if I have 20 planks of the same size, the solution is always: 2 trucks with each 10 planks. I don't need to try the combinations with 3 or more trucks.

If I have 21 planks of the same size, I only have to try all combinations that involve 3 trucks.

Comment: All the 10m planks MUST go on truck A. You want to put the remaining 5m planks on whatever truck has the lower cost for 5m planks.

Comment: Just to give you a search phrase that might help: Bin packing with general cost structures

Comment: @DXsmiley I guess you are right. I complicated the problem slightly by adding an extra truck and an extra plank type.

Comment: That's now more difficult. Given that the bounds on how much each truck can carry is quite small, you should look into [Dynamic Programming](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/).

Comment: @SebastianK thanks, the first hit on that query links to a paper that seems to be about exactly this problem. http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.5051v1.pdf

Comment: I don't understand people voting "Too broad". If my question was "Make me this algorithm" I would agree, but I'm just asking what the more general version of this problem is, which makes it especially narrow.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a generalization of the bin-packing problem which makes it a NP-hard problem. Refer to this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem